# Word is cropping and adding white instead of a full image

Tags: microsoft-word, images, png

I am trying to insert a PNG image into my word document, but it doesn't insert the full image and instead inserts a cropped version of it with some image being just white:

[image: Partial image]

The full image is supposed to be:

[image: Full image]

I am not super sure why this is happening. I also noticed that if I paste it as bitmap, then it is the only way to have the full image in the word document.

Moreover, I noticed that some of the images became corrupted:

[image: Corrupted image]

[image: Corrupted image]

I have some of the images saved and can try re-insert as bitmap, but some of images are no longer on my hard drive.

I also know that if I convert the document from `docx` to `doc`, then some of the image are just grey squares, and when I insert the same image, the image is inserted without any issue.

I tried pasting it as Bitmap (using `CTRL + ALT + V`), and it worked well. When I `Insert` it using the word menu, it is clipped. Are there any special setting I need to tweak for insertion of the images?

Is there a way to somehow restore the corrupted images? I found an older version of the document where the images look alright, I would probably need to save them and re-paste them again. I would like to avoid corruption in the future? Does anyone know why this is happening? Can anyone think of anythin?

Comment: Which version of Word are you using? On which operating system?

Comment: It's the word that is coming with the Office 365. I've tried two different laptops that run Win 10, and I also tried it on a friend's MacOS. I was able to find a version where it doesn't display correctly on the MacOS and another Win 10 machine, but it DOES work and displays image without cutting them on a 3rd laptop. I will try to update the application, and try to see if maybe it's Win related. I also tried to enable and disable hardware acceleration, but that didn't solve anything.

Comment: It sounds like you are running into a RAM problem on the first computers. RAM is one of the least expensive upgrades for a system. If you save a document as HTML you will get a folder with the images in it. If you insert from the images produced there, it may work.

Comment: I will try to save it as HTML, but this all seems too strange to me because the computer with 32GB of RAM and a dedicated GPU RTX-2060 cannot display an image vs 16 GB of RAM and Intel integrated GPU can...

Comment: How much RAM on the RTX 2060? Might that be the limiting factor? Please do check the PIXEL width and height of those images and tell what you have.

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text - [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Plausible cause #1:

"Too large image", in the respect that Word attempts to gobble up the required amount of RAM - and fails in that.

---

*Note 1: If the image is in the clipboard (you just pasted it!) then there is at least two copies of it in RAM.*

*Note 2: PNG may be a 3x16 bit image (color depth, requires more RAM), and "bitmap" might be a lot less than that.*

*Note 3: You have not revealed enough details to allow s more precise assessment.*

Comment: What other details can you think of? I know that if I convert the document from `docx` to `doc`, then some of the image are just grey squares, and when I insert the same image, the image is inserted without any issue.
As to what of cause 1, I tried pasting it as Bitmap, and it worked well. When I `Insert` it using the word menu, it is clipped. Are there any special setting I need to tweak for insertion of the images?

Comment: I've updated the post with some more information.

Comment: Nothing of it changes what I say above. As it stands now my suggestion is: buy more RAM or replace the (old?) computer with a newer one, while making sure it has more RAM.

Comment: This all seems too strange to me because the computer with 32GB of RAM and a dedicated GPU RTX-2060 cannot display an image vs 1GB of RAM and Intel integrated GPU can...

Comment: Should I try with a machine with 64GB of RAM just to be able to insert an image in word?

Comment: PNG and BMP are lossless, and it appears that BMP uncompressed takes more space than PNG. Is word doing some on the flight compression from the memory buffer?

Comment: The amount of RAM available to (on?) the GPU might also be a bottleneck.